# Ошибка компиляции в codeblocks

Tags: c++, g++, codeblocks

g++/Code::Blocks/Ubuntu Gnome
При попытке компиляции из codeblocks указанного ниже кода вылетает ошибка. Но любопытен тот факт, что выполнение тех же команд из терминала компилирует код без ошибок.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Лог в C::B:

-------------- Build: Debug in Test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++ -Wall -fexceptions -g  -c /home/egor/Документы/Projects/Test/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o
g++  -o bin/Debug/Test obj/Debug/main.o
g++: error: obj/Debug/main.o: Нет такого файла или каталога
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

Проверил, файл по такому пути существует, папка obj/Debug существует.

Comment: Конечно, маловероятно, но, возможно, проблема в том, что путь содержит русские символы (папка `Документы`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Действительно, попробовал сохранить проект в путь без русских букв и ошибка пропала. Просьба, отпишитесь как настроить codeblocks, дабы тот мог компилировать в папку с русским именем.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <iostream>
```

using namespace std;

```
int main(){
int x;
int y;
int m;
cin y;
cin x;
cin m;
switch x;{
case *:
return y*m;
system("pause");
break;
case +:
return y+m;
system("pause");
break;
case -:
return y-m;
system("pause");
break;
case /:
return y/m;
system("pause");
break;
```

}
}

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Извините, а зачем вы опубликовали здесь этот фрагмент нерабочего кода?